# Mesh with cloth simulation and particle instance modifiers (used in a particle system) not responding to wind

Tags: particles, cloth-simulation, force-fields

I want to create a simulation of leaves blowing in the wind using blender v2.72, just like [this tutorial](https://vimeo.com/12068802) ([archive](https://cgcookie.com/archive/creating-a-scene-of-blowing-leaves/)).

My problem is, I can't get the wind force field to act on the cloth simmed leaves once they are emitted by a particle emitter. nHere is a breakdown of what I tried to get the wind blowing.

I created a plane (at 0,0,0) as a particle emitter, adjusted the number of particles to 20, set the start and end frames to 1 and adjusted the lifetime to 2000. Under velocity, I set random to 0.2. I then set the physics to off ("No" in the settings) and switched off the rendering of particles.

I created another plane (also at 0,0,0) to act as the leaf mesh, subdivided it a few times in edit mode, applied a particle instance modifier to it, and selected the emitter plane as the object, I also checked "size" in the "create from" field to make the leaves smaller. After this, I applied cloth simulation to this "leaf" plane.

I then created a ground plane, scaled it up to 2, placed it below the emitter plane at (0,0,-0.2) and applied collision physics to it.

At this stage, hitting play results in the "leaves" realistically falling down onto the ground plane with cloth physics working.

The problem is I then can't get a wind force (in the physics tab) to act upon the leaves.
I tried adding an empty and applying a wind force field to it, but no matter where this wind field is directed and no matter how strong I make it, the leaves don't react to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the leaves is too small that is what causing the leaves to not respond to the wind force to solve this :

- scale up all the objects involved in the simulation
- move the emitter further from the ground to give the leafs space to fall
- increase the size of the particles in the physics panel :

[image]

here is the result :

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, this definitely works and I would vote up your answer if I had the reputation to do it.Just to help anyone that was having the same problem, as Chebhou said, scale up the objects in the simulation. In this case, I scaled up the emitter plane and the ground plane ( I left the wind empty and the cloth simmed leaf at their original sizes).

Comment: If you could add as a blend file it would be most appreciated.